# Mysql datetime entry with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cant enter `now()` to MySQL column which has `datetime stamp` option:

```
$sth = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (id, user_id,data,datetime,desc) ".
                   "VALUES ('', '$userid','$data',now(),'$desc')",$link)
       or die("Query  failed ");
```

MySQL:

```
4   datetime    timestamp           No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Output:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'desc) VALUES ('', '','',NOW(),'')'
at line 1
```

Comment: `NOW()` is a MySQL function. Remove the quotes around it.

Comment: YES, and make it capitalize NOW() not 'now()'

Comment: mysql extension has been deprecated

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

Comment: Please paste the table schema of your database. You get it via PHPMyAdmin -> Export.

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes for `now()` as it is a MYSQL function. Also it is not now(), it is `NOW()`.

```
$sth = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (id, user_id,data,datetime,desc) VALUES ('', '$userid','$data',NOW()),'$desc'",$link) or die("Query  failed ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is because `desc` and `datetime` are a reserved words, and if `id` is `AUTOINCREMENT` you can remove from values. Try this:

```
$sth = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (user_id, `data`,`datetime`,`desc`) ".
               "VALUES ('$userid','$data',NOW(),'$desc')",$link)
   or die(mysql_error());
```

And remember that `mysql` extension is deprecated, check mysqli or PDO.

Edited: Added some error detection

Comment: thats because the 'desc' i changed it to description and its okay

Comment: datetime is a reserved word too and i'm not sure about `data`, this is why i escape it too. And if you try some things and do not work, update your question please